# Chrome extension: extension logo image doesn't appear or get loaded although specified in manifest file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I click the [image] button in https://chrome://extensions and it loads my extension. However the image/logo of the extension is the default one instead of the one I provided:

[image]

**manifest.js**:

```js
{
  "name": "My App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My extension doesn't do anything yet!",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["js/clear_history.js"]
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "images/logo.svg",
    "96": "images/logo.svg"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/logo.svg"
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
  "permissions": ["history", "storage"],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["logo.svg"]

}
```

Project directory:

[image]

How do I fix it?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: @wOxxOm No. It's an extension icon. See EDIT to post

Comment: That's a bug then. Try a PNG icon.

Answer (score 1):

## WebP and SVG files are not supported.

Check out https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/icons/

You need to convert it to `.png` or `.jpg` file.

### For V3 Users

`manifest.json` should be modified. Below is my example.

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  
  // ...
  
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "images/*" // <---------- location of your image path
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```